# Deployment error for primefaces app to jboss7

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss7.x

I have a primefaces app which I want to deploy to JBoss7.1 I deploy it from eclipse, and the application gets deployed without any errors. However when I try to access the URL I don't get anything, no data.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Staring JSF -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- JSF URL mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>less</extension>
    <mime-type>stylesheet/less</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

and my pom.xml

```
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.wiw</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.wiw</groupId>
<artifactId>wiw-fe</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>wiw-fe Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring-social.version>1.0.3.RELEASE</spring-social.version>
    <spring-social-twitter.version>1.0.5.RELEASE</spring-social-twitter.version>
    <spring-social-facebook.version>1.0.3.RELEASE</spring-social-facebook.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>primefaces-repository</id>
        <name>Primefaces repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Prime Faces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF 2 API --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social Web (contains login/signup controllers) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social Twitter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-twitter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-facebook.version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>

    <finalName>wiw-fe</finalName>


    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the app? What you're getting? 404, blank page?

Comment: Nothing, not even 404. But the request is sent.